# kubernetes how to open diapason ports in pod

Tags: image, kubernetes, port

I have the manifest file and I know how to open the port if hi single, but I don`t know how open diapason ports (containerPort: '10000-20000') for the pod.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: asterisk
    image: asterisk
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "systemctl start asterisk"]
    ports:
    - name:  sip
      containerPort:  5060
      protocol: UDP
    - name:  ssh
      containerPort:  22
      protocol: TCP
    - name:  sip-connect
      containerPort: '10000-20000'
      protocol: UDP
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported by Kubernetes.